# database table design for storing different sized datasets

Tags: arrays, ms-access, database-design, dynamic-arrays, variable-length

I am designing a Microsoft Access database to store results from lab equipment.  They are in the form of hundreds of lists of frequency vs. response curves which I have previously stored rather easily, but inefficiently in Excel.

The difficulty comes from the fact that the frequency can vary from 1 - 50E9 Hz, the step size between data points can vary from 1 - 1E9, Hz, and the number of points can vary from ~ 100 - 40,000.  This has brought up a challenge when it comes to table design because everything I try seems to be very inefficient.

I have considered using links to external text files to store the data points which solves the table design, but seems to violate good database design.  I've considered using tables of arrays (i.e. Start Freq, Stop Freq, Freq Step Size, and Array of Responses), but the array sizes could vary greatly which seems just as inefficient.

Is there a recommended practice for storing this type of data?  It seems like a common task when storing instrument data, but I can't seem to find anything in web searches.  Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It can be very easily implemented if any of NoSQL databases can be used like MongoDB etc. Actually NoSQL DB are made for such datasets. But not sure about MS Access.

Comment: Any reason why you cannot store each of the array or responses as a row with its associated ID to start, stop etc data?

Comment: I may not understand your comment, but I think it's very similar to the answer by Mr. DImitrijevic below.  I'll definitely give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a classic 1:N relationship to me. "1" is the measurement session and "N" is all the measurements (i.e. data points) taken in that session. This is modeled by two tables and one foreign key between them, similar to this:

[image]

Tweak the fields to suit your needs, but this general design should be more than able to handle large amounts of data and varying numbers of measurements per session.

That being said, MS Access has historically had significant limitations on the size of the data that can be stored in a single database. If you hit these limits, consider using a "real" DBMS.

Comment: I hadn't considered this approach probably because I thought I'd overpower the limitations of Access. With 100 measurements with an average of 10,000 datapoints each, I'd have 1E6 rows in my table.  It certainly solve the problem of dissimilarly sized datasets so I'll definitely give it a try.  Is there anything more "elegant" that may be a more complex table design, but results in faster or more efficient operation?

Comment: @CLAKE1978 This is **the** relational way of modeling this kind of data at the logical level. However, there are things at the physical level that can be adjusted to the benefit of performance. For example, consider [clustering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) the MEASUREMENT table (so measurements of the same session are stored physically close together, benefiting range scans enormously). Unfortunately, this technique is available only in some DBMSes (including Oracle, MS SQL Server and MySQL/InnoDB).

Comment: @CLAKE1978 BTW, a million rows is considered "small" in the database world (but not necessarily for MS Access).

Comment: I initially rejected this approach due to it still requiring me to include three fields for Measurement (session id, freq, response).  This seems wasteful because frequency tends to follow a standard progression with three key pieces of info (Start Freq, Stop Freq, and Step Size).  However, if I don't include Freq in my Measurement, I will lose the order of my Responses.  Perhaps including Freq in Measurement table isn't a huge deal, but it seems to double the size of my table.  This is why I was thinking of arrays, but got caught up in the fact that they'll be different lengths.